# Como consumir api en Vue?

Tags: javascript, php, api, vue.js

Estoy tratando de consumir esta api de php en vue pero no me carga ningún items

````
    this.listapacientes()
  },

  data () {
    return {
      Items: {}
    }
  },

  methods: {
    listapacientes: async function () {
      try {
        const setting = {
          method: 'GET'
        }
        const url = 'https://localhost/api/pacientes.php'
        const data = await fetch(url, setting)
        const json = await data.json()

        this.Items = json
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }

})```
````

{"status":"ok","result":[{"id_cliente":"19",
"nombre":"Jul","apellido":"Sal","tipo_documento":"NIN","us_id":"5"}]}```

el resultado en Vue es 0 items

[image: Vue Resultado]

Comment: no es data.result?

Comment: No me funciona sale el mismo error

Comment: Te sugiero ocupar la librería Axios para Vue, [aquí puedes encontrar una referencia de la librería](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html?redirect=true) y es muy sencilla de ocupar. Además, te sugiero que debugges tu petición desde a sección de Network para verificar que tu solicitud está regresando datos. Saludos.

Comment: Okey, Gracias lo utilizare